# JsonResult is not identify from Angular 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am using VS 2015 with Angular 4. I have common controller method to make http request.

```
 public JsonResult Get(string endpoint)
    {
       // from Rest sharp
        var result = _restsharpClient.Get<List<object>>(endpoint); 
        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my angular class, I call this method make http request

```
return this.http
        .get('/Home/Get?endpoint='http://examplecode/API/gettestmethod')
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return <myclass[]>response.json();
```

When I debug the code I return data successfully to result variable. But for the angular, I get an empty array. Any idea?

Comment: check in the network tab of your browser to see what data is actually being sent back in the http response, the problem probably there or in the way you map the variable to your myclass[].It's hard for us to tell without this kind of info.

Comment: not enough information to help, what's the component using this data look like?

Comment: My data will be dynamic. because I just need to have one controller with common type. I solved the issue after removing JsonResult and adding Object as my return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create on array variable and call this.variable.

```
Public result:any=[];

return this.http
        .get('/Home/Get?endpoint='http://examplecode/API/gettestmethod')
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.result=response.json();  });
```